# Error with RoadModel.getDistanceOfPath(RoadModel.getShortestPath(Vehicle, Point))

Tags: java, rinsim

I'm trying to get get the expected time it would take to move to a specific point. Here is the code I am using:

```
long getTimeToReachGivenPoint(Point point) {

    System.out.println("Point: " + point);

    List<Point> path = getRoadModel().getShortestPathTo(this, point);

    System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    System.out.println("Path length: " + path.size());

    Measure<Double,Length> distance = getRoadModel().getDistanceOfPath(path);   

    long time = (long) (distance.getValue()/AgvAgent.SPEED);
    return time;
}
```

When I run this i get the following output:

```
point: (8.0,36.0)
Path: [(12.0,28.22222222222222), (12.0,32.0), (12.0,36.0), (8.0,36.0)]
Path length: 4
```

And the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not get connection length from a non-existing connection.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:135)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.geom.AbstractGraph.connectionLength(AbstractGraph.java:48)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.GraphRoadModelSnapshot.getDistanceOfPath(GraphRoadModelSnapshot.java:83)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.DynamicGraphRoadModelImpl.getDistanceOfPath(DynamicGraphRoadModelImpl.java:226)
at project.agents.AgvAgent.getTimeToReachGivenPoint(AgvAgent.java:162)
at project.agents.AgvScheduler.calculateExpectedPickUpTime(AgvScheduler.java:116)
at project.agents.AgvScheduler.getReservationProposal(AgvScheduler.java:43)
at project.agents.AgvAgent.getReservationProposal(AgvAgent.java:147)
at project.smartMessage.ExplorationAntComputationalBehaviour.compute(ExplorationAntComputationalBehaviour.java:41)
at project.smartMessage.ExplorationAntComputationalBehaviour.run(ExplorationAntComputationalBehaviour.java:75)
at project.smartMessage.AntAgent.run(AntAgent.java:64)
at project.agents.AgvAgent.tickImpl(AgvAgent.java:205)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.pdp.Vehicle.tick(Vehicle.java:55)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.time.TimeModel.tickImpl(TimeModel.java:139)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.time.SimulatedTimeModel.doStart(SimulatedTimeModel.java:32)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.time.TimeModel.start(TimeModel.java:94)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.ui.SimulationViewer$5.run(SimulationViewer.java:401)
```

From what I understand it seems there are no connections between the points on the path that is returned by the getShortestPath() method?

Comment: For now I fixed if with

Measure<Double, Velocity> maxSpeed = Measure.valueOf(getSpeed(), getRoadModel().getSpeedUnit());
  
List<Point> path = new LinkedList<>(getRoadModel().getPathTo(this, point, this.timeUnit, maxSpeed, GeomHeuristics.euclidean()).getPath());

But i'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong above or if it is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getDistanceOfPath(Iterable<Point>)` method requires all points in the path to be a node in the graph. The path returned by `getShortestPathTo(RoadUser, Point)` may contain a position that is not a node in the graph in case the `RoadUser` is not on a node. There is currently no built-in way to detect this and work around it.

You can detect this situation by using the `GraphRoadModel.getConnection(RoadUser)` method and if the `RoadUser` is on a connection then you can use the `Connection.to()` as the starting point for the `getShortestPathTo(RoadUser, Point)` call. For example:

```
Optional<? extends Connection<?>> conn = ((GraphRoadModel)getRoadModel()).getConnection(this);
Point from;
double dist = 0;
if( conn.isPresent() ){
  dist += Point.distance(getRoadModel().getPosition(this),conn.to());
  from = conn.to();
} else {
  from = getRoadModel().getPosition(this);
}

List<Point> path = getRoadModel().getShortestPathTo(from, point);
Measure<Double,Length> distance = getRoadModel().getDistanceOfPath(path); 

// total distance is the sum of distance and dist
```

Comment: The RoadModel I use is CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl. Somehow this makes the getConnection() method invisible, not sure why? But I tried casting the RoadModel to GraphRoadModel but when i do `Optional<Connection<LengthData>> conn = model.getConnection(this);` I get the error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<capture#1-of ? extends Connection<?>> to Optional<Connection<LengthData>>`

Comment: It is working if I cast the road model and use `Optional<? extends Connection<?>>` as the type of conn.